# back button logout symfony2 php error

Tags: php, symfony, button, logout, back

I am developing a Symfony2 app and I have a problem.

When I log out of my app, it does it correctly, but if I press the back button of the browser, I go back to a page which is in the logged.

If I write the URL to go to this page, I can't.

Thanks in advance

This is my Security.yml

```
security:
encoders:
    Simple\ProfileBundle\Entity\User:
        algorithm:        sha1
        encode_as_base64: false
        iterations:       1


role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_ADMIN:       [ROLE_USER]


providers:
    main:
        entity:
            class: Simple\ProfileBundle\Entity\User
            property: username

firewalls:
    secured_area:

        pattern:    ^/
        anonymous: ~
        form_login:
            login_path:  login
            check_path:  login_check
            always_use_default_target_path: true
            default_target_path: /logged/portada
        logout:
            path:   /logout
            target: /portada
access_control:
       - { path: ^/logged, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

Comment: you checked that you have unset $_Session/cokkie or any variable allowing you to stay in?

Comment: Yes, I unset all cookies and destroy the session, but it still go back. I think it could be because the browser cache, but I can't deactivate it.

Comment: What does your `security.yml` file look like? Have you actually followed [the instructions relating to security](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html) in the Symfony docs or did you just write your own Security application layer? Symfony will tell the browser to cache pages if it doesn't acknowledge certain routes or paths as secure.

Comment: The page is most likely cached by your browser. No actual request is send to the server, so you can't prevent this behaviour.

Comment: So I can't do anything??

Comment: Have you added a route for `/logout` to your `routing.yml`?

Comment: No, I have added a route in `/portada`, because it's the target. Am I wrong?

Comment: [Yes, you have to create a route for the logout firewall function](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#logging-out). See the third code snippet in my reference. This may not fix the problem but let's eliminate this issue first

Comment: Oh sorry, I had it, I thought you were saying if I had the route for a controller in the logout routing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tested your scenario successfully in my own Symfony 2.3 applications and found that it is in fact a security flaw that comes from the browser cache (not a framework issue because it's out of the control of the framework.)

Here is a [discussion around the issue](http://forum.symfony-project.org/viewtopic.php?f=21&t=28479). The general (but not complete) solution is to send "Expire" headers that the browser may (or may not) pay attention to when you use the back-button behaviour. [Here's the Symfony docs for HTTP Cache headers](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/http_cache.html)

I have not tested it in a 2.5.* environment yet, so this may have been addressed in a later version of Symfony.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I'm new in Symfony and I didn't know why it was failing.